# Capturing VPN Interface on Windows 10 black holes Traffic with Wireshark

Tags: windows-10, vpn, wireshark

I need to see if some issues that are occurring are due to the network, and want to start on the client to see why google speed test is failing over the VPN on the Windows 10 client. I admin the VPN gateway so I could do a more laborious capture there on my client but I would like to Wireshark capture the VPN adaptor interface. I can do this from the GUI but all traffic stops passing as soon as the capture begins, and starts again as soon as I stop the capture. Happens if I run as normal or admin user. Has anyone else seen this and got a workaround/solution?

Comment: Does Windows actually support that on the TAP Adapter?  The TAP adapter is a fairly limited network adapter, as Windows' network stack doesn't support vLANs, so OpenVPN had to develop software to get around this to be able to create a vLAN interface - the TAP Adapter - but it's an extremely limited network adapter.

Comment: It’s a native VPN - so a PPP adapter from ipconfig output

Comment: After the VPN is started, if you then start Wireshark, does it see a TAP adapter or one that looks like "WAN (PPP/SLIP) Interface"? If it sees it then it might be able to monitor it. The [WinPcap FAQ](https://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm#Q-5) however says no, but it's pretty old.

Comment: It appears as a LAN connection, I can capture on it but it stops any traffic from leaving the interface, I’m unable to access the network as the capture starts and can access it again as soon as I stop it

Comment: I would uninstall Wireshark, check wheter both npcap and winpcap are uninstalled, and install Wireshark again.

Comment: Also there might be a problem with some 3rd party firewall application. Maybe you can start by installing the Windows 10 OS in a VMWare, set up VPN and Wireshark, and test again?

Comment: There's no network firewall on box other than windows defender fw and traffic works fine without wireshark so why would that break it if i'm sniffing? Have uninstalled and reinstalled with various different options and nothing seems to work on that front

Comment: Having the same problem. I'm trying to sniff a VPN interface and the pings stop as soon as I start capturing and start back up again as soon as I stop it.

Answer (score 6):

Select PPP connection's Ethernet interface in the WireShark interface list and disable "promiscuous mode" in capture settings.

Otherwise, it seems to stop "any traffic from leaving the interface"